# Two contradictory statement in the book <General topology> by Stephen Willard

Tags: general-topology

There is a statement In 8D

> If $X_\alpha$ is a nonempty topological space and $A_\alpha \subset X_\alpha$, for each $\alpha \in A$, then $\prod A_\alpha$ is dense in $\prod X_\alpha$ if and only if $A_\alpha$ is dense in $X_{\alpha}$, for each $\alpha$.

There is a statement In 8E:

> Let $X_\alpha$ be a nonempty topological space for each $\alpha \in A$, and let $X = \prod X_{\alpha}$. If $b_\alpha$ is a fixed point in $X_\alpha$, for each $\alpha \in A$. Then $B = \{x \in X | x_\alpha = b_\alpha \text{except for finitely many}   \alpha \in A\}$ is a dense set in $X$, i.e. $Cl_XB =X$

If 8D is true, How can a single point in $X_\alpha$ be dense ?

Comment: $B$ is not of the form $\prod A_\alpha$, so your first statement says nothing about it.

Comment: The set $B$ is not a cube (it cannot be written as the product of subspaces of the $X_\alpha$)

Comment: @RobertIsrael I think B is of the form: $\prod {b_\alpha} \times \prod X_\alpha(finitely)$

Comment: No, that's wrong. Actually the right conclusion is that 8D and 8E together imply that $B$ therein is not of the form $\prod_\alphaA_\alpha$ (unless perhaps in some pathological situations).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$B$ is **not** of the form $\prod_\alpha A_\alpha$ so that theorem does not apply.

It *can* be written we a union

$$B = \bigcup_{F \subseteq A\text{ finite }} \{\prod_{\alpha} A_\alpha : \forall \alpha \in F: A_\alpha = X_\alpha; \forall \alpha \notin F: A_\alpha = \{b_\alpha\}\}$$

but that's a lot bigger than just a single such product... And each subset we take a union of is not dense, but their union is dense, sort of like no $\{q\}, q \in \Bbb Q$ is dense, but their union is.